# Dual boot Ubuntu 15.04-windows 8.1 ubuntu missing boots to windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.04, windows-8

I am new to ubuntu and recently installed it to my HP Pavillion g7 (model number escapes me) and have been using it successfully for several weeks now when i logged in today to find that the grub boot menu did not appear, instead it booted directly into windows much to my surprise! I checked my partitions to find that where ubuntu was once installed, there was only free space. Is it possible that ubuntu migrated or deleted itself? Or did windows eat it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows cannot or does not want to read ext4 file systems, that's why you see them as empty. Assuming you have a Windows 8 or 10 operating system installed in UEFI mode, follow this :

1. Boot into Windows installation and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot**.

   To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

   ```
   powercfg /h off
   ```

   To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
   select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.
2. **Shut down** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot** !
3. reinstall the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.
   Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - then  open a terminal and execute:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
   sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
   for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
   sudo chroot /mnt
   grub-install /dev/sd*
   update-grub
   ```

Note:

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use **GParted**.
The tool is included in the Ubuntu install media.

Boot into BIOS and change the boot order in UEFI settings.
Select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.

You can select which OS to boot from the GRUB boot menu.

Comment: I don't think i have options for the boot order in my BIOS. can i do it from windows cmd line?

Comment: @basilisk_64 : No you can not change the boot order from within Windows except if you modify the BCD store and add ubuntu to it - but that would be another question - please check the BIOS options - I never heard that you cannot change the boot order in BIOS/UEFI ... :)

Comment: also, for partition options on /dev/sda i have ntfs, fat32 (boot), ext4, and linux-swap. which one is which?

Comment: @basilisk_64 : ntfs for Windows | fat32 (boot) for boot loaders | ext4 and linux-swap for ubuntu ... :)